# mysql query apply condition to where clause only if certain condition satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add condition_2 to mysql where clause by test condition_1. condition_1 is `type = 'group:1'` and condition_2 is `username = 'rahim'`. So, if `type = 'group:1'` satisfied, then I going to add `username = 'rahim'` in where clause. If not satisfied, I do not want to add this to where clause. I tried  `username = 'rahim' CASE WHEN type = 'group:1'`. But, it output error:

> [Err] 1064 : for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN type =
>   'group:1' AND type = 'group:1''

```
 SELECT
    a.user_id,
    b.username,
    a.message,
    a.type
FROM
    livechat_message a
LEFT JOIN livechat_user b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE
    username = 'rahim' CASE
WHEN type = 'group:1'
AND type = 'group:1'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
WHERE NOT (type = 'group:1' AND username <> 'rahim')
```